# set constructor with custom compare function

Tags: c++, set, compare

How is the y.size() = 4 in the following? The values in y are {11, 2, 4, 7} How does one arrive at this? What are a and b in the operator() function for each iteration of the set. I don't understand the construction of y and I can't find anything online that explains this situation. Thank You

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct C
{
    bool operator()(const int &a, const int &b) const
    {
        return a % 10 < b % 10;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::set<int> x({ 4, 2, 7, 11, 12, 14, 17, 2 });
    std::cout << x.size() << std::endl;
    std::set<int, C> y(x.begin(), x.end());
    std::cout << y.size() << std::endl;
    std::set<int>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = y.begin(); iter != y.end(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second template argument of [set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is comparator type — type of functor that implements less operation.

```
struct C
{
    bool operator()(const int &a, const int &b) const
    {
        return a % 10 < b % 10;
    }
};
```

This comparator will compare `a` and `b` as `a < b` only if `a % 10 < b % 10`, so practically all numbers will be compared by modulo 10.

UPDATE:

After pushing into `x` set numbers `{ 4, 2, 7, 11, 12, 14, 17, 2 }`, set will contain seven elements `{ 2, 4, 7, 11, 12, 14, 17 }`. These elements will be sorted in that way, because `set` stores objects in sorted way.

Then numbers from `x` set are being sequentially inserted into `y` set. Before inserting of each element, `set` will find proper place in sorted order of currently inserted numbers. If `set` will see, that there is already some number on it's place, `set` will not insert it.

After inserting `{2, 4, 7}` from `x` to `y`, `y` will be `{2, 4, 7}`.
Then, to insert `11` into `y` `set` will do comparisons of `11` with `{2, 4, 7}` to find proper place using provided `C` functor.
To check is `11` less than `2` `set` will call `C()(11, 2)`, which will result in `11 % 10 < 2 % 10` comparison, which will result in `true`, so `11` will be inserted before `2`.

Other numbers from `x` (`12, 14, 17`) will not be inserted, because `set` will find, that `12` should be on place of `2` (because `2 % 10 < 12 % 10 or 12 % 10 < 2 % 10` expression is false, so `2 == 12`), and in same way `14` and `17`.

Comment: but what are the two values being compared? How does one get the value of 11 for the first element of y?

Comment: @VarsMolta, Because 11 mod 10 is less than 2 mod 10, 4 mod 10, and 7 mod 10.

Comment: @VarsMolta I updated answer with detailed explanation.

Comment: @rutsky thanks! very well explained.in general, is using the functor more efficient than writing your own function to do this or are they equivalent? say if we have millions of numbers in the set

Comment: @VarsMolta Custom comparators usually used to make code cleaner and more logical. Comparator defines custom *order* on elements, which is a common pattern. Also, comparator class can be reused: you can use it in structures like `set` and `map`, in STL algorithms like `lower_bound` and `sort`. If you find my answer useful, please mark it as accepted.