# Find largest 4 values of a local maximum

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

My program produces the following output at some time[image]

and at some time later

[image]

and I would like to determine the largest 4 values of BOTH crests. I've managed to find the largest 4 values of the largest crest (see the code below), which is relatively simple because I basically need to find the absolute largest values. But I don't know how to find the largest 4 values of the smaller crest, and I was wondering if anybody could help me with this?

---

Here is the C++ code I used to find the largest 4 values of the largest crest:

```
for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)
{
    queue_matrix[i] = 0.0;
}

for(i=0;i<SPACE;i=i+1)
{
    if(U_field_matrix[i][t1] > queue_matrix[0])
    {
        queue_matrix[0] = U_field_matrix[i][t1];
    }
}

for(i=0;i<SPACE;i=i+1)
{
    if((U_field_matrix[i][t1] > queue_matrix[1]) && (U_field_matrix[i][t1] < queue_matrix[0]))
    {
        queue_matrix[1] = U_field_matrix[i][t1];
    }
}

for(i=0;i<SPACE;i=i+1)
{
    if((U_field_matrix[i][t1] > queue_matrix[2]) && (U_field_matrix[i][t1] < queue_matrix[1]))
    {
        queue_matrix[2] = U_field_matrix[i][t1];
    }
}

for(i=0;i<SPACE;i=i+1)
{
    if((U_field_matrix[i][t1] > queue_matrix[3]) && (U_field_matrix[i][t1] < queue_matrix[2]))
    {
        queue_matrix[3] = U_field_matrix[i][t1];
    }
}
```

Comment: For a continuous function, the local maxima/minima occur where the derivative is zero.  The discrete version would be maxima where the change from one value to the next goes from being an increase to a decrease.  Looking at the differences between values might help. This would get messy where there is little change (the flat parts) or if the curves aren't smooth, but you could work around this.

Comment: Main problem is deciding what constitutes a crest. Is "hill" a crest (height is 0.6, but width is 40)? What is a crest's minimum height? Maximum width? Actually what exactly is a width?

Comment: @e0k your comment was very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by @e0k's comment (thank you!), the following code will determine the largest 4 values of both crests.

```
for(i=0;i<SPACE;i=i+1)
{
    if((U_field_matrix[i][t1] > 0.1) && (U_field_matrix[i+1][t1]-U_field_matrix[i][t1] < 0.0))
    {
        counter1 = i;
        break;
    }
}

for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)
{
    queue_matrix1[i] = 0.0;
}

for(i=(counter1-3);i<(counter1+4);i=i+1)
{
    if(U_field_matrix[i][t1] > queue_matrix1[0])
    {
        queue_matrix1[0] = U_field_matrix[i][t1];
    }
}

for(i=(counter1-3);i<(counter1+4);i=i+1)
{
    if((U_field_matrix[i][t1] > queue_matrix1[1]) && (U_field_matrix[i][t1] < queue_matrix1[0]))
    {
        queue_matrix1[1] = U_field_matrix[i][t1];
    }
}

for(i=(counter1-3);i<(counter1+4);i=i+1)
{
    if((U_field_matrix[i][t1] > queue_matrix1[2]) && (U_field_matrix[i][t1] < queue_matrix1[1]))
    {
        queue_matrix1[2] = U_field_matrix[i][t1];
    }
}

for(i=(counter1-3);i<(counter1+4);i=i+1)
{
    if((U_field_matrix[i][t1] > queue_matrix1[3]) && (U_field_matrix[i][t1] < queue_matrix1[2]))
    {
        queue_matrix1[3] = U_field_matrix[i][t1];
    }
}

for(i=SPACE;i>-1;i=i-1)
{
    if((U_field_matrix[i][t1] > 0.1) && (U_field_matrix[i-1][t1]-U_field_matrix[i][t1] < 0.0))
    {
        counter2 = i;
        break;
    }
}

for(i=0;i<4;i=i+1)
{
    queue_matrix2[i] = 0.0;
}

for(i=(counter2-3);i<(counter2+4);i=i+1)
{
    if(U_field_matrix[i][t1] > queue_matrix2[0])
    {
        queue_matrix2[0] = U_field_matrix[i][t1];
    }
}

for(i=(counter2-3);i<(counter2+4);i=i+1)
{
    if((U_field_matrix[i][t1] > queue_matrix2[1]) && (U_field_matrix[i][t1] < queue_matrix2[0]))
    {
        queue_matrix2[1] = U_field_matrix[i][t1];
    }
}

for(i=(counter2-3);i<(counter2+4);i=i+1)
{
    if((U_field_matrix[i][t1] > queue_matrix2[2]) && (U_field_matrix[i][t1] < queue_matrix2[1]))
    {
        queue_matrix2[2] = U_field_matrix[i][t1];
    }
}

for(i=(counter2-3);i<(counter2+4);i=i+1)
{
    if((U_field_matrix[i][t1] > queue_matrix2[3]) && (U_field_matrix[i][t1] < queue_matrix2[2]))
    {
        queue_matrix2[3] = U_field_matrix[i][t1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was hesitant to post this, because you seem to have a really simple usecase, which your solution probably covers sufficiently well, but there are really nicer ways to look for top-k values. In general you would probably do yourself a favor, if you split this up into a function that looks for maxima (according to what eOk said, if this works for you), a function that looks for top-k and a program which runs over your data and calls the top-k function on the surrounding values whenever it finds a maximum.

I don't have a solution like that lying around right now, and without knowing about the types of your variables, it is impossible to write one for you, but top-k for example usually looks like this for me:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
template <class in_iterator, class out_iterator,                                
        class value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<in_iterator>::value_type,
        class compare = std::greater<value_type>>                               
void findTopK(in_iterator start, in_iterator end, out_iterator out,             
        size_t k)                                                               
{                                                                               
    std::vector<value_type> heap;                                               
    heap.reserve(k + 1);                                                        
    for (;start != end; ++start)                                                
    {                                                                           
        heap.push_back(*start); //min-oriented heap, order implied by compare   
        std::push_heap(std::begin(heap), std::end(heap), compare());            
        if (heap.size() > k)                                                    
        {                                                                       
            std::pop_heap(std::begin(heap), std::end(heap), compare());         
            heap.pop_back();                                                    
        }                                                                       
    }                                                                           
    while (!heap.empty())                                                       
    {                                                                           
        std::pop_heap(std::begin(heap), std::end(heap), compare());             
        *out++ = heap.back();                                                   
        heap.pop_back();                                                        
    }                                                                           
}
```

This method uses a heap to keep track of the k largest elements. Calling it on a regular array works as well as on any container and looks like this:

```
int main()                                                                      
{                                                                               
    int array[] = {1,3,4,5,6,2,62,3,32};                                        
    std::vector<int> results;                                                   
    findTopK(std::begin(array), std::end(array), back_inserter(results), 5);
}
```

As a result you don't have to write the k counterx loops every time, and your code becomes more readable. The difficult part for you may be providing a custom compare-function for your elements, but there are enough posts on this on so:

[Custom comparator for set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920111/set-constructor-with-custom-compare-function)

Comment: Thank you midor. Allthough I will not implement this solution for this particular case, I'm sure that at some point in the future I will need something more sophisticated and so your answer is still useful! +1

Answer (score 0):

At every graph you should find crests looking for values for `x axis = i` greater than value for `x axis = i + 1`. You will get the two crests, larger value is for larger crest. Then, compare each value with the set of values found previously